# angularJS $http.get(localhost/teste) não funciona no Chrome

Tags: html5, angularjs, google-chrome

No meu controller possuo um  `$http.get(http://www.testesitelocal.com:18888/teste_json)` que me retorna os valores do JSON teste. Faço essa requisição na minha maquina local. No Webview que fiz em JavaFX isso funciona normal, mas no Chrome não funciona (no Firefox e no IE ocorre a requisição normal).

Retorno do erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://www.testesitelocal.com:18888/teste_json` . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://www.testesitelocal.com:8000 <http://www.testesitelocal.com/>'` is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui achar a resposta! Olhem:

#### Definição de domínios explícita: ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108538/cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-is-true) e [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i))

Configuração do JavaScript:

**Com jQuery/Zepto:**

```js
function verificaCodigoTurma(codigo, retorno) {
  try {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      timeout: 5000,
      //async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      //crossDomain: true,
      url: 'http://TESTESTE/VERIFICA',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: '{"sch_code":"' + codigo + '", "app_id":1}',
      //JSON.stringify(teste),
      success: function (data) {
        retorno(data);
      }
    });
  }
  //Exceção geral da sincronização
  catch (err) {}
}
```

**Sem jQuery / Vanilla-JS:**

```js
function verificaCodigoTurma2(codigo, retorno) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var params = '{"sch_code":"' + codigo + '", "app_id":1}';

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.ETESTEr.com.br/Services/TESTE.svc/TESTE", false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  //Para funcionar, além da configuração abaixo é necessário colocar o seguinte header no servidor:
  //Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
  xmlhttp.send(params);
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  retorno(jsonResponse);
}
```

Você ainda pode usar [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), no caso de requisições GET.

Para que o CORS funcione você deve também configurar o servidor:

**IIS:**

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Apache:**

```apache
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Lembrando que essas configurações acima permitem que qualquer website acessem dados do seu, retirando a segurança dele. Por isso procure restringir os domínios cobertos pela `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

**Crédidos:** *Airton Barbosa que conseguiu e foi atrás da resposta correta e ainda ofereceu mais de uma solução*

Comment: Deixando de lado a desorganização, algo que alguém irá arrumar, vale lembrar que *é melhor arrumar a aplicação para funcionar com CORS do que desativar a segurança do Google Chrome*.

Comment: Propus uma edição, mas não mudei o código, só passei ele no [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). Se alguém tiver um código mais limpo por favor edite.

Comment: Só agora parei pra ver que quem respondeu foi o autor da pergunta.

Comment: hehehehe É que achei a resposta e postei rápido....me desculpe.

Comment: O *menino que vive morrendo* editou o post e não sei onde a minha proposta de edição foi parar: eu tinha reescrito os códigos. Depois edito novamente.

Comment: Tranquilo! Depois dou uma passada no seu servidor de minecraft ;) abs